# What does the phrase 'much the most" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases, is-it-a-phrase

Is it really a phrase?
I found it in Tom Sawyer - "...and the most hospitable and *much the most* lavish in the matter of festivities that St Petersburg could boast..."

Comment: I think this is one of the lesser-known adverbial meanings of much to "almost."

Comment: Obviously it is “really a phrase”, since you found it in *Tom Sawyer*.

Comment: @tchrist :any light on the meaning?

Comment: Sure: it means something along the lines of *“and rather more lavish”* or *“and by far the most lavish”*.

Comment: which is quite opposite of what @JamesMcLeod  surmised...

Comment: @Swami That’s hardly my fault, now is it? :)

Comment: No, it isn't. I walk out of the discussion, like a confused customer!

Comment: Swami, have you consulted a dictionary/ searched on line?

Comment: I consulted Oxford, it does mention an example of this kind but there is no meaning provided.

Comment: I don't enjoy reading Mark Twain's broken English, legitimized by the modern excuse of "idiomatic" language.

Comment: That's an inevitable part of classic English literature, either it's broken or it's 'thou-thee-thy'. Just saying.

Comment: I think it correct if used in such an authentic novel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Much the <superlative>" is relatively uncommon, but nonetheless well attested.

Not many dictionaries seem to mention it explicitly; one that does is *Macmillan Dictionary*, which includes it in sense 2 ("used for emphasizing that someone or something is a lot bigger, better, worse etc"):

> **much the biggest/best etc (=a lot bigger, better etc than all the others)**: *I got lots of lovely presents, but yours was much the nicest.*

[[link](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/much_1)]

Comment: That’s OED sense 2c. There’s no accounting for lesser dictionaries. :)

Comment: I suspect James McLeod has a point, too -- see the comment at OP.

Comment: @Kris He may have a point, but he’s wrong. Stop trolling.

Comment: @tchrist We could be just as wrong as anyone else. Let's not forget that.

Answer (score 1):

According to Michael Swan's Practical English Usage, this structure: much/quite + superlative noun phrase is mostly British. It is like by far+ superlative noun phrase. Quite in this structure means absolutely. For example: He is quite the most stupid man I've ever met.